# Clear glasses without "ghost" double images?

Tags: glasses

I've been looking for a good pair of glasses for low-light or nighttime cycling.  I've tried a few pairs but all have the same issue: a "ghost" double image of any bright lights.  It can be a bit disorienting. It seems to be due to some sort of internal reflection.

I've tried the Oakley Fast Jacket and Smith Pivlock V2, and the clear and orange lenses that go with both have the same issue.  Are there any glasses that don't have this problem?

Comment: Wear glasses for 60 years and you'll learn how to ignore it.

Comment: Maybe it's because I wear glasses (Well, contacts anyway), but I wear Oakley clear lenses in various editions without any double images all the time.

Comment: I use BBB frames with prescription lenses and clear outer lenses at night with no problems to report.

Comment: Thanks, all.  I tried a number of other glasses at various shops and couldn't find any without the issue.  Then, on a whim, I tried on some ski goggles with a very thin and flexible clear lens.  Amazingly, they didn't have the issue!  My guess is that the lens is thin enough that the reflected image appears at the same place as the real image.  So, now I'll be looking around for some safety goggles with very thin lenses.

Comment: Very often ski goggles have an anti-reflective coating.  (The problem with such a coating is that it's very soft and will either scratch or wear off fairly rapidly.)

Answer (score 2):

Anti-reflective coating is the first solution that comes to mind.  No brand of clear-lens safety glasses occurs to me, but you might try a trick I used many years ago when I commuted by motorcycle in less than optimal lighting or weather: Car-wax the lenses.  Keeps softer plastics from scratching as badly, and changes the surface characteristics of the more modern and harder plastics.  Give the wax plenty of drying time or the fumes will make your eyes burn.  You might want to have an eye exam as well.  Second surface reflection could be a symptom of something a professional could correct.

Comment: The anti-reflective coating definitely sounds like a good idea.  I looked around and can't find anyone that will apply it to non-prescription lenses, unfortunately.  Can you say what you mean by the eye exam?  I only have the issue when wearing the safety glasses, not without.

Comment: @samsamoa you should be able to get it applied to new plain lenses for prescription glasses if that's any use - some people only need corrective lenses for one eye but may still want both coated.